# sum same condition in multiple columns to get a total

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I've been trying to sum the same condition in different columns (and different sheets) to get a total.
For example, I have a list of items in 3 different columns with 3 different sums.

See here:

[image: sheet1]

I solved this with an SQL query within Google sheets but I'm looking for a more simple/ elegant solution.

This is what I have:

```
=UNIQUE({QUERY(A2:I8; "SELECT SUM(C) where B LIKE 'bananas'");
QUERY(A2:I8; "SELECT SUM(F) where E LIKE 'bananas'");
QUERY(A2:I8; "SELECT SUM(I) where H LIKE 'bananas'")})
```

And the result looks like this:

[image: total]

Does someone know a shorter version that fits in one cell?

Comment: so you are not looking for "sum per row" solution as on the 2nd image, right?

Comment: hello player0, no the query is to long and the result is to long....i'm looking for a shorter formula, query and shorter result in one cell, so no "sum per row"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUM(QUERY({A:C;D:F;G:I}; "where Col2 = 'bananas'"; 0))
```

---

```
=QUERY({A:C;D:F;G:I}; "select sum(Col3) where Col2 contains 'banana' label sum(Col3)''")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=SUM(FILTER({C:C;F:F;I:I}; {B:B;E:E;H:H}="bananas"))
```

[image]

Comment: @ player0 thank you for the solutions! Let me play around with it a little but because it's throwing parse errors

Comment: @Tom fixed. try now

Comment: @ player0 , great solutions! Especially the 2nd one :) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: one more question@ player0 , how do I use the 2nd solution =SUM(FILTER({C:C;F:F;I:I}; {B:B;E:E;H:H}="bananas")) for data populated on another sheet?  stuff like this didn't work: =SUM(FILTER({sheet1!C:C;F:F;I:I}; {sheet1!B:B;E:E;H:H}="bananas")) ?

Comment: use: `=SUM(FILTER({sheet1!C:C;sheet1!F:F;sheet1!I:I}; {sheet1!B:B;sheet1!E:E;sheet1!H:H}="bananas"))`

Comment: suppose I have an extra column with dates and I would like to use (filter and sum) only the rows of the last month. Is that possible with =TODAY()-30?